# Linking/Registering a .so File

Tags: c++, linux

I've just compiled a test application using some libraries provided by a custom third party vendor. There is no installation/package manager. The application builds as expected. However, when I go to run it, it can't seem to find a necessary .so file (which I've got sitting in the same directory):

```
[diego@localhost Debug]$ ls
esdcan  libntcan.so.3  makefile  objects.mk  sources.mk  src
[diego@localhost Debug]$ ./esdcan
./esdcan: error while loading shared libraries: libntcan.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[diego@localhost Debug]$ ldd esdcan
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff125ff000)
    libntcan.so.3 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00000031d2600000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00000031c7600000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00000031c8600000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00000031c7200000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000031c6e00000)
```

I'm missing some step I'm sure, I'm just completely unaware of what that step is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `ldconfig` after completing the build, as well as making sure that the current directory is inside your `/etc/ld.so.conf` file so that the current directory is a trusted directory to look for shared libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable to current directory

```
[diego@localhost Debug]$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./esdcan
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> /etc/ld.so.conf           File containing a list of colon, space, tab,  new-
>                           line,  or  comma-separated  directories in which to
>                           search for libraries.
> ```

Also you can set the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy it into somewhere like /usr/lib (which is a bit invasive), or you can try setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH=[absolute(?) path containing libntcan.so.3]:LD_LIBRARY_PATH before running.